# Where and how to download and install PyROC

Tags: python, download, installation, logistic-regression

I'm new to machine learning and am trying to plot a ROC to determine the sensitivity and specificity of my logistic regression. I understand that Python has built-in modules with PyROC to facilitate this process. However, I have looked everywhere on the web but am unable to find where I can download the package containing PyROC. (pip install pyroc won't work until this package/module has been downloaded). Can you please point me to where I can download the necessary packages for me to be able to use PyROC functions in my program? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to download it from here:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marcelcaraciolo/PyROC/master/pyroc.py

I don't see a pip installable version.